# no write permission to memory card storage from termux

Tags: external-sd, storage, permissions, terminal

is it possible to write/edit the files on the memory card with [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en_US&gl=US)

i tried the command:
`termux-setup-storage`

but it only gives the permission to write on my device storage(*/emulated/0/*)

Comment: Writing to the external sd-card section is only possible using the Java-API. As Termux applications are usually regular Linux programs writing to the external sd-card is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: If your device is rooted you can use root to write to memory card.

Comment: is it possible if i use beanshell[on termux] to write into memory card