# Termux access /sdcard/data

Tags: data-monitoring, file-permissions, termux

**Most of the apps are now not permitted to access /sdcard/data**

- the only app i know which can access this folder is Files(not files by google)[com.google.android.documentsui]
- a few days ago i see this app called [X-plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en&gl=us)

```
~ $ ls /emulated/0/Android/data/
ls: cannot access '/emulated/0/Android/data/': No such file or directory

~ $ ls /sdcard/Android/data/
ls: cannot open directory '/sdcard/Android/data/': Permission denied
```

It asked the permission to access this folder, with files like allowing access to newly inserted memory card,

---

***is there a way to make termux ask to allow access to that folder***

---

or, is there a command to do it like, termux-setup-storage

Or is there a way to do it directly with `am` command

And I'm **not a rooted user**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no write permission to memory card storage from termux](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230706/no-write-permission-to-memory-card-storage-from-termux)

Comment: you have misconception here `/sdcard` is actually **not** your (external) MicroSD Card unless you formatted it as [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) which makes it (internal) shared storage

Comment: your question lacks basic information about phone and can't be answered

Comment: there is no confusion between */storage/emulated/0 = /sdcard* but confusion with *"newly inserted memory card" (/storage/FFFF-FFFF)*

Comment: you still did not mention phone model and android version. works fine on Poco M3 MIUI 12 Android 10 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc25g.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you are talking about `/sdcard/Android/data` instead of `/sdcard/data`.

From what I gathered, this is an intentional "security" feature. It is possible to bypass by root, but that is not an option for you.

There is the permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, so if you manage to grant it to termux it should theoretically work, but may require some app patching to the manifest beforehand.

The last thing you can do is use adb on yourself using localhost with adb over network and edit the files from `adb shell`, that however requires the use of the `run-as` command which only works for debuggable apps.

*I will look into more solutions and edit this answer later.*

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE applies to scoped storage android 11 (unrelated to MicroSD Card)